# Add layout handle based on dynamic value

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout

I need to add a specific layout handle for all the pages when a certain value is present in the session.
To make it more clear, if `$session->getMyValue()` returns `true` I need to load a specific layout handle called `my_specific_layout_handle` on every page I visit.
In the code above `$session` is an instance of any subclass of `Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager` (not really relevant).
Is there any event I can use or any method I can pluginize?

Note: I'm not concerned with full page cache for now. Let's say it does not exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Adding Layout Handles You Can Use Event Also:

In Your **events.xml**

```
<event name="layout_load_before">
   <observer name="load_custom_handler" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore" />
</event>
```

In Your **LayoutLoadBefore.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

use [Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Session; //this is a custom session that extends `\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager`
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout;

class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    const MY_SPECIFIC_LAYOUT_HANDLE = 'my_specific_layout_handle';
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * LayoutPlugin constructor.
     * @param Session $session
     */

    public function __construct(
        Session $session
    )
    {
        $this->session = $session;        
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       if ($this->session->getMySpecificSessionValue()) { // YourCondition
           $layout = $observer->getLayout();
           $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle(self::MY_SPECIFIC_LAYOUT_HANDLE);
       }

       return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. This looks more elegant than my solution  because I'm sure that my layout handle is loaded last.

Comment: @Marius, You are always welcome :), and thanks to you for your inputs in community

Comment: Hello, but it would be great if you create a custom layout file.

**layout/category_custom_layout.xml**  and add this line in body tag
**<attribute name="class" value="category-custom-layout" />**

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do it by pluginizing `Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout::addDefaultHandle`.

I added this in `di.xml` of my module

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout">
    <plugin name="my-plugin-name" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Result\LayoutPlugin" />
</type>
```

Then created the file.  `[Vendor]/[Module]/Plugin/Result/LayoutPlugin.php`

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Result;

use [Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Session; //this is a custom session that extends `\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager`
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout;

class LayoutPlugin
{
    const MY_SPECIFIC_LAYOUT_HANDLE = 'my_specific_layout_handle';
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * LayoutPlugin constructor.
     * @param Session $session
     */
    public function __construct(
        Session $session
    ) {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @param Layout $layout
     * @param $response
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterAddDefaultHandle(Layout $layout, $response)
    {
        if ($this->session->getMySpecificSessionValue()) {
            $layout->addHandle(self::MY_SPECIFIC_LAYOUT_HANDLE);
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but I am open for other suggestions.

Comment: You can use event also , if you need then I can give you

Comment: sure. It wouldn't hurt to try

Comment: @Marius, I added answer using event as Murtuza Suggested